# Prevent specific RSS feed from redirecting to feedburner but let main feed redirect

Tags: wordpress, rss, feedburner

On a wordpress site:
I'm trying to prevent a specific "sub" feed from redirecting to feedburner, but I want to allow the main feed to continue to redirect.

the feed I want to prevent the redirect on is setup like: 
http://website-example.org/feed?author=275

but keep http://website-example.org/feed redirecting to feedburner.

Currently I am using PHP to create the redirect. my code looks like this:

```
add_filter('feed_link','custom_feed_link', 1, 2);

function custom_feed_link($output, $feed) {
    $feed_url = 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/websitename/yaSQ';
    $feed_array = array('rss' => $feed_url, 'rss2' => $feed_url, 'atom' => $feed_url, 'rdf' => $feed_url, 'comments_rss2' => '');
    $feed_array[$feed] = $feed_url;
    $output = $feed_array[$feed];

return $output;
```

}

I found this answer here, but I'm not sure if it is the best way to do it. (also, I don't completely understand the code for it.)
[How to redirect main all feed to feedburner except some feeds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11697192/how-to-redirect-main-all-feed-to-feedburner-except-some-feeds)

Can someone tell me if I am on the right track, or if there is an easy solution for this, or what the .htaccess code in the link above means.

Thank you,
Ian

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

I ended up using a custom RSS template and an older plugin called "feed wrangler".
The solution works quite well.

Here are some helpful links:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/feed-wrangler/
http://kanevski.org/projects/feed-wrangler/